# Using JS/JQ class constructor cannot get HTML audio element to play

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio

I have the below HTML

```
<div data-song="song1" class="songs">
    <audio id="song1">
        <source src="audio/song1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element
    </audio>
</div>

<div data-song="song2" class="songs">
    <audio id="song2">
        <source src="audio/song2.mp3">
        Your browser does not support the audio element
    </audio>
</div>
```

and the following Javascript/jQuery:

```
var songs={};
$(".songs").each(function(){
    let id=$(this).attr("data-song");
    let song=$("#" + id);
    songs[id]=new Music(song);
    songs[id].play();
})

function Music(song) {
    this.song=song;
    this.play=function(){song.play();};
}
```

When I attempt to play them, as at the end of the $(elem).each, I get the error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: song.play is not a function
>      at Music.play (main.js:37)
>      at :1:15

Where am I going wrong? This seems simple.

Comment: I think you need the audio element and not the jquery object within Music.

Comment: Thanks! changes $("#" + id) to document.getElementById(id).

Comment: That can work or use `$("#id")[0];` this will return the HTML Element. See posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would try one of the two possible solutions:

**Solution 1**

```
var songs={};

$(".songs").each(function(){
    let id = $(this).attr("data-song");
    let song = $("#" + id)[0];
    songs[id] = new Music(song);
    songs[id].play();
});

function Music(song) {
    this.song=song;
    this.play=function(){song.play();};
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
var songs={};

$(".songs").each(function(){
    let id = $(this).attr("data-song");
    let song = $("#" + id);
    songs[id] = new Music(song);
    songs[id].play();
});

function isjQuery(obj) {
    return (obj && (obj instanceof jQuery || obj.constructor.prototype.jquery));
}

function Music(song) {
    this.song = isjQuery(song) ? song[0] : song;
    this.play = function(){song.play();};
}
```

The second one is a little more robust. This way you can use Music with an HTML element or a jQuery object.

Hope that helps.